# Set dependent Notes in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

I'm looking for a way, to automatically generate notes, depending on the contents of another cell. For example: A1 has a text "xy" and I want B1 to have that text "xy" as a note. And if I change the text of A1, I want the note of B1 to change as well. This must be achievable somehow right?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#setnotenote

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#getnote

Comment: @Cooper have inform you how you will use note, and you can combine it with on edit or on change event to define when you create note and when you clear note.

Comment: The question isn't clean. I think it corrupts the rules. Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can catch EDIT event and update your notes

```
/**
 * @file Updates notes in the second column if there have been edits in the first one.
 * @url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58685598/set-dependent-notes-in-google-sheets
 */

/**
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Events.SheetsOnEdit} e
 */
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getColumn() === 1)
    e.range.offset(0, 1).setNotes(e.range.getValues());
}
```

Comment: As a plus, I would add this function to initialise the values in the notes ```/* Run this function to initialize values in the notes */
function setNotes(){
   var sheet  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var valuesA = sheet.getRange('A1:A' + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();    
   sheet.getRange('B1:B' + sheet.getLastRow()).setNotes(valuesA);   
   Logger.log(valuesA);
}```